Formatting control points for BSplineFunction
I am trying to create an approximation to a level surface $F(u,v,w) = 0$ using BSplineFunction and control points sampled from the ContourPlot. I want to use these points to make a 2-variable BSplineFunction, but I do not know how to arrange them properly into an array that the function can understand. Can someone help?
Here is my current code:
F1 = {u, v, w} |-> 
   2 + 12 u - 30 u^2 - 40 u^3 + 30 u^4 + 12 u^5 - 2 u^6 - 28 v^2 - 
    48 u v^2 + 56 u^2 v^2 + 48 u^3 v^2 - 12 u^4 v^2 - 8 v^4 + 
    48 u v^4 - 24 u^2 v^4 - 16 v^6 + 4 w^2 - 48 u w^2 + 88 u^2 w^2 + 
    48 u^3 w^2 - 12 u^4 w^2 + 48 v^2 w^2 + 96 u v^2 w^2 - 
    48 u^2 v^2 w^2 - 48 v^4 w^2 + 56 w^4 + 48 u w^4 - 24 u^2 w^4 - 
    48 v^2 w^4 - 16  w^6;
L=2;
rpoints = RandomPoint[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    ContourPlot3D[
     F1[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, {z, -L, L}, 
     Mesh -> None, Lighting -> None]], 50000];
f = BSplineFunction[rpoints];


The code fails at generating the rpoints, not at the BSplineFunction level. Could you explain a little more clearly what you are trying to accomplish? Would the output of ContourPlot (not 3D) with a fixed value for one of the parameters do what you want?
